# SAS Rename file on SFTP

Tags: sas, sftp

my task in SAS is to upload a file via SFTP with extension tmp and after the upload is finished to rename it to csv. As I am no adminstrator of the server my debugging output is limited and I am struggeling with the correct implementation. The following code generates no error in the SAS Log but does not rename the file:

```
%let host=...;
%let sftpUser = ...;
%let filename_tmp=20160301-test01-sas.tmp;
%let filename=20160301-test01-sas.csv;
%let sftpPath=...;

FILENAME test SFTP "&sftpPath.&filename_tmp." 
HOST="&host." 
USER="&sftpUser."   
DEBUG;

proc export data=.... outfile=test dbms=csv replace; 
run;

data _null_;
rc=rename("test&sftpPath.&filename_tmp.", "test&sftpPath.&filename.", 'file');
run;
```

I already read the docs for filename and rename but I could not get a clue on how to combine both statements - any help or hints or alternatives are greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Stephan

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot perform the rename locally before the sftp?

Comment: hello floydn, yes, there is one indeed. There is a script running on the destination server scanning for csv files and move them every minute so there is the danger that a file is moved when the upload is not completed. Therefore I would like to upload them as tmp and rename it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a script running on the destination server scanning for csv files and move them every minute so there is the danger that a file is moved when the upload is not completed.

I'm pretty sure that there's no danger of the file being moved, as it should be locked until the upload completes.  Just try it.

Comment: Hi Crna Krv, thanks for your feedback - I tested it with an export of a file with a lot of rows and the file was removed during the export. I therefore need to implement the rename version.